# C++ API with cURL

Tags: c++, api, curl

Alright so I was looking up an API with PayPal and have noticed that they do not have a C++ api but has a cURL api. (I have no knowledge of cURL) but from what I have read it deals with libcurl and libcurl is a free client-side URL transfer library, supporting FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP etc.

So wouldn't that mean if you have a decent understanding of Winsocks and the HTTP protocol you could work with the PayPal API?

Or how does one use a website's data with no API. "Paypal" for example.

Answer (score 0):

> So wouldn't that mean if you have a decent understanding of Winsocks and the HTTP protocol you could work with the PayPal API?

You just need to know the web site's HTTP protocol, and libcurl would enable you to implement it.

> Or how does one use a website's data with no API. "Paypal" for example.

You should probably wrap some basic operations into c++ classes and functions yourself to hide the low level libcurl API calls.